# How does Java print a String?

Tags: java, encoding

Java uses char array to store String and String uses UTF-16 to store characters.

For my ubuntu:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

If the encoding of my java source file is UTF-8, and the main content is:

```
System.out.println("你好");
```

The meaning of `你好` is `hello`. With UTF-8, `你` and `好` both need 3 bytes to store. With UTF-16, they need 2 bytes.

When `你好` is printed to screen, is the data that Java sends to Linux OS  encoded with UTF-8 or UTF-16 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.out` is a `PrintStream`, which in turn uses `StreamEncoder` to encode the String (atleast in Java 6).

`StreamEncoder` is asked to use the encoding the OS expects. So in your case,  it outputs in UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

```
String text = "你好";
byte[] array = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String s = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(s);
```

You can try with UTF-16 if you want UTF-16